# log4net and NoSQL logging

Tags: nosql, log4net

Is it possible to log events with log4net to a NoSQL database like MongoDB?
Is there a custom appender for that?

I would like separate separate my logging data from my application data in Postgres, as they differ in the amount of write operations (most logging) and backup requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Log4mongo-net?](https://github.com/log4mongo/log4mongo-net)